# Margin not working with FrameLayout and weight

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this xml layout which is parent layout for FrameLayouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_card_row1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_card_row2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my separate single FrameLayout that is populated in parent Layout shown above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/book_corners"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/home_item_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/book2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-12px"
        android:layout_marginTop="-12px"
        android:cropToPadding="false"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/single_book"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_item_badge"
            style="@style/round_badge"
            android:text="34"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_item_big_badge"
            style="@style/big_badge"
            android:text="Updated 30 minutes ago"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home_item_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is the very cool title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home_item_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="And this is some very nice description about content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_item_preloader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-12px"
            android:background="#333"
            >

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And what happens is that when I inflate that parent xml with its FrameLayout childs everything is fine, but when I try to programatically add that FrameLayouts from separate xml then left/right margins disappear.
Why is that happening?

Comment: FYI, `sp` should be used for Font size and `dp` should be used for dimensions.

Comment: put that code as well. you should set layout params when you add a view programmatic

Comment: Are you certain that this is your layout? There are two problems with it: 1) the namespace declaration should only be on the root element and 2) the FrameLayouts are possibly not being used as they don't have IDs.

Comment: thnx for tip, Paresh. I've just updated xml. yes, it shouldn't contain namespace declaration - it was my mistake when preparing this to show you. @vipul, code is very simple. It inflates that root view (in this case linear layout with two nested rows) and then inflates that FrameLayout from another xml file which has specified margins in it for the root and then I just add that View to specific row of LinearLayout. No magic here. It works, but doesn't set margins properly even though they are specified in xml.

Comment: I've edited my code do be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `sp` (scale pixels) which is used for font size, you need to use `dp` (density pixels) which is used for dimensions in your `FrameLayout` as below:

Same for all the margins and paddings where you have used `sp` instead of `dp`.

```
   <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: ok, now it works when I add margins programatically. but this actually sucks that I cannot use parameters specified in layout and need to set them again :/

Comment: If you are adding views dynamically by coding then you have to set its each parameters programmatically only you can not refer the parameter from xml file directly.

Comment: or maybe this is because setting layout params programtically resets all previously set params in xml? Because what I was doing programatically was only setting the weight of FrameLayouts. Maybe that has overridden another params set in xml?

Comment: Yes this can happen if you change the parameter of your layout programatically then it may affect the layout.